# GPG decryption :Exit code 1?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

`gpg` decryption is working fine when i run the script manually, however `gpg` commands exit with code 1 when invoked remotely using the same user.

Command is:

```
gpg --batch --yes --always-trust --exit-on-status-write-error \
    --passphrase "$pass_phrase" --output "$OUTNAME" --decrypt "$InName" >> $LOG
```

### Additional information:

```
pub   2048R/227932CF 2016-08-09
uid                  XXXX(Public Key XXXX) <xxxxxxx@xx.com>
sig!3        227932CF 2016-08-09  XXXX XXX (xxxxx) <xxxxxxx@xx.com>
sub   2048R/51F72098 2016-08-09
sig!         227932CF 2016-08-09  XXXX XXX (xxxxx) <xxxxxxx@xx.com>

pub   2048R/B15019CC 2016-05-29
uid
sig!         B15019CC 2016-05-29
sig!         227932CF 2016-08-10  XXXX XXX (xxxxx) <xxxxxxx@xx.com>
```

Does `!` not suggest that the key is verified? Does anybody know what could be wrong in the command which is why it ends with exit code 1, only if invoked remotely?

Comment: How are you invoking the command remotely. You use four variables in your command .. are those containing the right values when invoking remotely.

Comment: Yes I have applied echo in the script which tells me that all four variables are holding the correct information. The script works file when I run it using 'sh' or './'. And it is invoked using './scriptname parameter(filename)' once connection is established.. The script is running fine however the gpg commands ends with exit code 1.

Comment: Can sig!3 (extensive verification for key signature) could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide a command line without variables and the full STDOUT and STDERR output and what's written to the `$OUTNAME` file. Include `-vv` for more verbose output. Create a test key if necessary, and include the GnuPG version (`gpg --version`). As is, your question is incomplete and cannot be answered.

Comment: Hi Jens, Sorry about the incomplete question. the GPG version I am using is `gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.5
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions. See the file COPYING for details.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
`

Comment: The command is 'gpg --batch --yes --always-trust --exit-on-status-write-error \
    --passphrase xxxxxxx --output /path/test.csv.pgp --decrypt /path/test.csv &> $LOG'

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved now. STDOUT and STDERR helped me to debug the problem, I wasn't aware of this since I am new to shell scripting and 'gpg' utility. It was the pass phrase that was getting parsed incorrectly when other users invoke my script.

Apologies for being silly. Many Thanks everybody!